# Given a numpy array of box coordinates, how to find total area of boxes taking into account box overlap?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an nx4 numpy array  of box coordinates where each has the format [xtl, ytl, xbr, ybr], is there an efficient (vectorized) way of finding the total area of the boxes in the array, taking into account that some of the boxes will overlap? i.e. if a box is completely inside of another box, its area should not be counted.

Comment: It's very memory inefficient, but setting up an array of bools then setting each box to true and counting the trues is not a bad option here. You can bound that array of bools to the max and min of the observed boxes.

Comment: seems that, the area of every box depends on the previous boxes ( bc the intersection). That seems imposible to vectorize. the coordinates are integers?

Comment: @UlisesBussi box coordinates are floats

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: That sounds just like project euler [problem 212](https://projecteuler.net/problem=212). You can find lots of solutions for this by googling "project euler problem 212 solutions." Here's [one](https://www.reddit.com/r/projecteuler/comments/lzazf/problem_212_combined_volume_of_cuboids/).

Comment: It's too broad. Research more, choose one library or algorithm, and ask a specific question. Anyway, if you are satisfied with an approximation, you can use the [MC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method). If you want an exact solution, you can use spacial analysis libraries such as Shapely, scikit-geometry, GeoPandas, etc.